# How DO I store/retrieve data and display them in templates?

Tags: theming, nodes, 8

Coming from THE MVC pattern of Django, I am unable to grasp the concept in Drupal 8. I know Twig is used for templating, but what about storing/retrieving data in Drupal 8 and displaying them in templates? Suppose I have a content type (*Activity*) with fields like *Image*, *Body*, *Files*, etc. Someone can create multiple activities with a WYSIWYG editor. How do I retrieve all these nodes and display them in a page applying my own styles (not using views). Django Views are suitable for this. Can I do this without developing a module?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is using preprocess function. In your theme's '.theme' file, write a preprocess function. Example:
In `bartik.theme`

```
function bartik_preprocess_html__node__28(&$vars) {

$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('type','article','=')
        ->condition('status',1,'=')
        -> execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $key => $value) {
$title = $value->title->value;

}
$vars['title'] = $title;

}
```

(node__28 is any node page where you want to see all results, I made this basic page)

Now in `html--node--28.html.twig` template, retrieve title of content type = `article`

```
{{ title }}
```

Comment: Any other way rather than preprocess method?

Comment: You can use views module - simple and easy way

Comment: Views are rather simple in a sense that it only supports fewer styling types like grid, list, etc. In django, I could directly create query into database, combine the data into json, and render the data to templates. How do I do so in Drupal 8?

Comment: You can use templates as per your style. You will get theme suggestions for building templates for views. Else if you want to enhance more styling options in views, then views' hooks are available to enhance the functionality. You can alter these styling types and enhance too by using Drupal's hook functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using views to build simple lists of things where "list" means a list, table, slideshow, or map. It is more maintainable for site builders. This is how you would accomplish this task *without building a module*. In other words, **use views**.

However, here's the custom module route if you want to do it all with code rather than out-of-the-box tools.

Drupal uses a presentation-abstraction-control (PAC) framework, which is similar to model-view-controller (MVC). In Drupal 8 this effectively means you can create a route and route controller to do business logic and then return a render array for the presentation/theming layer to consume.

1. Implement a route and controller in your custom module. You can inject the [entity.query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/service/entity.query/8.2.x) service into your controller a few different ways. Then load the entities that you wish via the Entity Query API (similar to an ORM query builder). The controller could also work similar to an entity list builder.
2. Assemble a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render) as the return value of the controller. You may want to use render elements or theme functions such as `container` or `table` or `item_list`, but you can implement your own templates with custom variables to use therein.